# Django Form to Update Quantity

Tags: python, django, django-forms, e-commerce

I'm using Django forms to update quantity of an item, and although it appears to me that I have everything structured properly, the form is not actually updating the quantity when I click 'Submit'. Of note, I am also not getting any errors -- as if the form is being accepted.

In forms.py:

```
class ChangeQty(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(label='', min_value=1, widget=forms.NumberInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = 'quantity'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChangeQty, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-exampleForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'submit'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Update', css_class='btn btn-md btn-primary'))

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('quantity', placeholder='Qty'),
        )
```

In cart.py

```
def add(self, product, unit_price, quantity):
    try:
        item = models.Item.objects.get(
            cart=self.cart,
            product=product,
        )
    except models.Item.DoesNotExist:
        item = models.Item()
        item.cart = self.cart
        item.product = product
        item.unit_price = unit_price
        item.quantity = 1
        item.save()
    else: #ItemAlreadyExists
        item.unit_price = unit_price
        item.quantity = int(quantity)
        item.save()
```

In views.py

```
def specific_qty(request, product_id, quantity):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChangeQty(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cart = Cart(request)
            cart.add(product_id, product.price, form.get('quantity'))
            return render_to_response("full_cart.html", dict(cart=Cart(request)), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = ChangeQty()

    return render(request, 'full_cart.html', {'form': form})
```

And lastly, in full_cart.html:

```
<li>Quantity:
    <form class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" action="." method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="{{item.quantity}}">
        <input class='btn btn-md btn-primary' type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
</li>
```

Comment: erm shouldn't that be form.cleaned_data['quantity']? Why not liberally sprinkle some log messages in your code to find out what's happening or run it under a debugger?

Comment: What is `Cart`? You are creating new `Cart` object `cart = Cart(request)` and never saving it. How is `Cart` is saved in `Item`?